# MS Edge loses focus after screen turns off

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a script which catches key press events and does something. It works fine until the screen turns off when I press again something the screen turns on and the browser doesn't get the keypress events in ms edge (in chrome/firefox it does).

The wierdest thing is that after 10 minutes of pressing something edge somehow "regains" focus and it starts working again.

https://jsfiddle.net/fymetro0/

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Pressed " + new Date().getTime();
});
```

Is this bug or feature of edge? Can I disable it somehow?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Updated fiddle with onblur + onfocus: https://jsfiddle.net/fymetro0/1/

In chrome/firefox it doesn't lose focus when the screen turns of but it does in edge.

**UPDATE2**
Ok, I am now pretty confident that's just how edge is. The ugly workaround is interval which checks every few seconds that the document has focus and if it doesn't it calls document.focus().

Comment: Did you click on the browser so it gets focus after the screen turns on? Test it by running `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` You'll only get key events if the window has focus

Comment: No, I didn't. If I mouse click then it works even in edge. (I turned the screen on by pressing some keys)

Comment: Well, there's your answer, the browser loses focus when the screen dims, it probably got focus again when you hit alt+tab or something like that

Comment: I am sure I am just pressing alphanumeric keys and enter. Why edge loses focus when the screen turns off?

Comment: Here's something else you can test, make sure your cursor is inside a text field, let the screen dim, then hit the keyboard again, see if text shows up in the text field. But ultimately, it just may be something that Edge does, lose focus

Comment: Is this mobile or desktop? What do you mean by when the "screen turns off"? I guess you mean on a mobile phone or tablet not a computer monitor?

Comment: It is some all-in-one pc - so basically desktop.